# 'global name @wraps is not defined' error in flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app, where i have implemented a snippet, to check if a user is logged in, in order to acces certain webpages on my application.

My method looks like this:

```
#check if session is avaliable to access hidden pages for non users
def is_logged_in(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'logged_in' in session:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash('Please Login ', 'danger')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return wrap
```

Here I check if the session has a `logged_in` attribute attached the the session.

However, I get an error saying `global name @wraps is not defined`,
but I have no idea as to why?

Comment: Did you mean to import wraps from functools?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you are probably missing wraps from functools

```
from functools import wraps
```